# Both source and destination disks won't boot after clone

Tags: windows-10, clone, nvme, acronis-trueimage

I've cloned a NVMe SSD to another SSD connected via SATA with Acronis bootable iso.
I accidentally pressed "To replace a disk on this machine Clone with bootable OS".
Currently both my disks won't boot.
I'm using Windows 10.
When I'm booting it shows "Please Wait" then asks to choose keyboard layout then I have three options, to use a device, Troubleshoot or Turn it off.
I've tried to remove the SSD and boot to the NVMe, to remove the NVMe and boot to the SSD, to rebuild the MBR on the SSD using AOMEI, change every boot setting in BIOS, reclone using a different build of Acronis, and run Startup Repair.
None helped, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the computer developed a hardware problem. I assume you're on Windows, so try to boot with a Windows boot media. Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I do manage to boot Acronis itself or Windows boot media. But not Windows.

Comment: I have Windows installation media

Comment: Try to [Run a Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I've tried that as well, I forgot to mention my bad

Comment: How has the Startup Repair failed? Have you tried to [Do a Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)?

Comment: I tried to do a Repair install, but it's required to boot to Windows first which I am not able to do.

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry. Try the Repair Install.